# Maxima. Как получить в переменную численное значение?

Tags: функции, математика

Вечер добрый!

Делал подобное задание:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге получил подобный код:

```
v(x,y,z):=(9*sqrt(2)*(x^3)) - ((y^3)/(2*sqrt(2))) - (4 * (z^3) / sqrt(3))$
u(x,y,z):=(z^3)/(x*(y^2))$
scalVU(x,y,z):=(''(diff(v(x,y,z),x)) * (''(diff(u(x,y,z),x))))+(''(diff(v(x,y,z),y)) * (''(diff(u(x,y,z),y)))) + (''(diff(v(x,y,z),z)) * (''(diff(u(x,y,z),z))))$
modgrV(x,y,z):=sqrt((''(diff(v(x,y,z),x)) ^2)+ (''(diff(v(x,y,z),y)) ^2)+(''(diff(v(x,y,z),z))^2))$
modgrU(x,y,z):=sqrt((''(diff(u(x,y,z),x)) ^2)+ (''(diff(u(x,y,z),y)) ^2)+(''(diff(u(x,y,z),z))^2))$
modgradVM: modgradV(1/3, 2, sqrt(3/2))$
modgradUM: modgradU(1/3, 2, sqrt(3/2))$
scalVUM: scalVU(1/3, 2, sqrt(3/2))$
answer: acos(scalVUM/(modgradVM*modgradUM))$
print("a = ", answer)$
```

В ответ он выводит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можете заметить ответ получается НЕ численный.

Как можно заставить эту шайтанку выводить его в численном виде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опечатка: определена функция modgrV, а использована modgradV, поэтому максима не знает как быть с этой функцией, и оставляет ее символьное представление. Если опечатку исправить, то ответ:

```
v(x,y,z):=(9*sqrt(2)*(x^3)) - ((y^3)/(2*sqrt(2))) - (4 * (z^3) / sqrt(3))$
u(x,y,z):=(z^3)/(x*(y^2))$
scalVU(x,y,z):=(''(diff(v(x,y,z),x)) * (''(diff(u(x,y,z),x))))+(''(diff(v(x,y,z),y)) * (''(diff(u(x,y,z),y)))) + (''(diff(v(x,y,z),z)) * (''(diff(u(x,y,z),z))))$
modgrV(x,y,z):=sqrt((''(diff(v(x,y,z),x)) ^2)+ (''(diff(v(x,y,z),y)) ^2)+(''(diff(v(x,y,z),z))^2))$
modgrU(x,y,z):=sqrt((''(diff(u(x,y,z),x)) ^2)+ (''(diff(u(x,y,z),y)) ^2)+(''(diff(u(x,y,z),z))^2))$
modgradVM: modgrV(1/3, 2, sqrt(3/2))$
modgradUM: modgrU(1/3, 2, sqrt(3/2))$
scalVUM: scalVU(1/3, 2, sqrt(3/2))$
answer: N(acos(scalVUM/(modgradVM*modgradUM))) $
print("a = ", answer)$
```

[image: acos((3^(7/2)/8-3^(11/2)/8)/(sqrt(2)*3^(7/2)))]

числовой ответ:

```
answer, numer ;
2.356194490192345
```

Или:

```
answer,expand;
```

[image: (3*%pi)/4]